# Order of Execution - Multiple Flows for the Same Object

Tags: visual-workflow, case, order-of-execution, unexpectedexception

Is there any order of execution when you have multiple flows for the same object?

I'm working in an org with many flows for the same type of object and getting intermittent 'UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION' errors that "self-resolve" without any changes additional changes.

I am familiar with SF order of execution here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

But not seeing anything that explicitly states there is or is not an order of execution to flows of the same object.

Anybody run into a similar issue or got clarification from SF on whether or not there is a guaranteed execution order?

NOTE: I think the solution here is consolidating the flows into a single flow with subflows, simply looking to be informed.

Comment: Have you looked at setting the [trigger order](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_trigger_order.htm&type=5&release=236) for each flow?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to David Cheng from comments.

- Flows with the same trigger (before- or after-save) on the same
  object with trigger order values from 1 to 1,000 run in ascending
  order (1, 2, 3, and so on).
- Multiple flows with the same trigger    order value run in
  alphabetical order based on the flows’ API names.    Flows without
  trigger order values run next and in the order of their    created
  dates. Flows in Winter ’22 and before run and continue to run    in
  this order, unless you define a trigger order value for them.
- Flows with trigger order values from 1,001 to 2,000 run next and in
  ascending order. Any ties are settled using the flows’ API names.

Link to documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_trigger_order.htm&type=5&release=236